# serialize array of object

Tags: c#, .net

```
[Serializable()]
public class A
{

        [XmlArrayAttribute("Item")]
        public  List<B> items;
}

[Serializable()]
[XmlType(TypeName = "Item")]
public class B
{

}
```

After serialization, I found I have something like

```
<Item>
   <Item> **** </Item>
   <Item> **** </Item>
    *****
</item>
```

But I only want

```
 <Item> **** </Item>
 <Item> **** </Item>
```

How to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class A
{
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<B> items;
}

public class B
{

}
```

Notice that you don't need the `[Serializable]` attribute. It is used only for [binary serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx) and ignored by [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) which is what I suspect you are using even if this should have been clearly stated in your question. Also for better encapsulation I would recommend you using properties instead of fields. And another remark: the standard naming convention in C# dictates that property names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: Thanks. When should I use XmlArrayAttribute?

Comment: When you want to generate and personalize a nested sequence of XML elements from that member.